# How to Resize an actor in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a small game in android with libgdx. My texture size is too big for my character and I am not able to resize the actor while creating the actor. Thanks in advance

```
setBounds(getX(), getY(), Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6);
```

Comment: show your code, where you are resizing ?

Comment: @Sreekanthss please check again

Comment: http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: @Sreekanthss Can I change the size with setBounds method

Comment: you can write some costume resize method or you can change it to  setBounds  as did in that tutorial

Comment: actor.setSize(0.2f*stage.getWidth(), 0.2f*stage.getWidth() * actor.getHeight()/actor.getWidth()): this is another way you can try

Comment: Do you mean the logical size, used for ingame logic or the optical size, the size of your `Actor`s `Texture` on screen? For the optical simply override the `Actor`s `draw()` method and use `batch.draw()` with a smaller `width` and `height`.

Comment: @Springrbua Can you please suggest a tutorial

Comment: You need to tell me, if you want to resize the `Texture` on the `Screen` or the logical size of the `Actor`

Comment: @Springrbua I want to make the actor suitable for the screen by comparing the screen width and height

Comment: So you need to adjust the `width` and the `height` in the `Spritebatch.draw` method: (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) Look for the right `draw` method, which has a `width` and `height` parameter and use different values until you see it works for you. You can also set a `Viewport` to your `Stage`. Just google for "libgdx stage viewport" and you will find some tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `draw()` a smaller `Texture` you need to adjust the `width` and `height` inside the `SpriteBatch.draw()` method, which you call inside `Actor.draw()`.
You could also set a `Viewport` to the `Stage`, so that you don't have to play arround with pixels. To see a few tutorials just google for "libgdx viewport stage". Also note the new [`Viewport`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) classes.